'SQLiteCommand' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteReader'
I am using SQLite4Unity3D plugin, because other alternative wasn't supporting android.
It was working fine but when it comes to read the select query I found the SQLiteCommand is not supporting the ExecuteReader method.
'SQLiteCommand' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteReader'

here is code I was trying
// establish connection with the database.
SQLiteConnection database = new SQLiteConnection(databaseName);
Debug.Log("Connection successful");
        
// initialize sql query.
string userInfo = "SELECT name, email, password FROM employee WHERE email = '" + email + "';";

// execute user account query.
SQLiteCommand user = database.CreateCommand(userInfo);
        
IDataReader reader = user.ExecuteReader();


its quite uncommon for using sql directly in an android app, in a game server, sure, but clients very much less so.. Second, SQL injection, third, SQL injection...
